# matlab: making script to analyze data from excel file

Tags: matlab, variables, if-statement

I am analyzing data from a behavioral experiment. I am reading my data from **one** excel file into matlab.

```
% load data
[num,text,raw] = xlsread('stop');
data=num(:,10); % column 10 in original excel file
```

The variable called `data` is a one-column vector (25000x1) containing results from all subjects.

```
data(1:227) is from subject 1. 
data(228:420) is from subject 2, and so on.
```

See a part of my data below:

```
Subject ID    Data
10011         384
10011         290
10011         508
10033         322
10033         361
10033         522
```

I need to get an output that is called `"data"`. These variables (`"data"`) should contain all data for each subject.

As of now I've created one variable per subject manually - which is not practical (100 subjects):

```
x1=find(num(:,1)==10011);
px1=data(x1,:); and so on up to 100th subject.
```

It would be better if this process could be automated as I have tried below:

```
subjects=[10011; 10033...];
for i=1:length(subjects)
 data=num((find(num(:,1)==subjects(i))),10);
end
```

If I exchange `data` with `data(i)` I'll get an error message. 
How can I do it?

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do. Are you only interested in column 10 of the excel sheet? Is each subjects' data set 277 numbers? What's the error message?

Comment: Each subject has a subject ID in column 1 for as many rows as they have the responses in column 10. I've used xlsread so that I have the numbers of the excel sheet in a matlab variable called data. I want to extract from this the responses in column 10 for each subject separately.  

Number of responses in subject's data set is not constant. Varies between 200-250. 
Error message: ???  In an assignment  A(I) = B, the number of elements
in B and
 I must be the same.
I am unsure why I get this error message. Because the number of responses differs per subject and I must use structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it as follows:

```
subjects=unique(num(:,1)); %note that 'subjects' will be sorted.
data=[];
for i=1:length(subjects)
    temp1=num((find(num(:,1)==subjects(i))),10);
    %now two options, either save the data for each subject in a different cell, as follows:
    data{i}=temp1; %if you do this, you can replace temp with data{i}. Also remove the line: data=[];
    %or save it in a matrix but then you cannot differentiate between data of different subjects. For that, you have to write another code.
    data=[data;temp]; %this is where you need temp
end
```